# yadcf - Select - Split multiple values onto separate lines in cell

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I am using yadcf on datatables.js to populate and filter a column Select e.g. a list of Countries.   The select contains unique values for country such as:

Austria

France

Italy

USA

UK

A record can have multiple values for Country. For example a record might have "USA" and "UK".  The countries display in the cell like this:

> > USA,UK

I want the values for Country to display on separate lines within the cell, like this:

> > USA
> >
> > UK

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You want to split the values inside the table cell or inside the filter select input cell? if its inside the table itself then its not related to yadcf.

Comment: Yes inside the table cell.  So presumably it would be done within datatables.js?

Comment: Its surely not related to yadcf, but I think its not even related to datatables as well, but rather to your table layout itself, its up to you to arrange your `<table>` and its `<tr>` and <td>` the way you want it to... B.t.w yadcf can handle multiple values per cell thanks to the `text_data_delimiter` option, see 4'th column in the showcase http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source.html

Comment: Yes I played around with text_data_delimiter, I read about it in the notes inside the yadcf javascript file. - I thought I could use <br /> as a delimiter and split the content that way, but I couldn't get it to work, even replacing ',' with '++' as a test. Would a '<br / >' work in there?

Comment: provide a minimal jsbin sample of your table in order for me to try and help

Comment: I've added it here:  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a207139777aeba2ef9d7    thanks.

Comment: I meant a jsbin/jsfiddle working sample (something that is possible for working/editing/debuggin)

Comment: Hi Daniel it's running inside .Net MVC but I've added the html and javascript here https://jsfiddle.net/westtown/1af38htj  Is this enough?  Do you need some data?

Comment: No, but its ok, alredy did a little setup of my own, see it working http://jsbin.com/facuxeluya/edit?html,js,output I suspec tthat you have white spaces in your cell and not `WordOne<br>WordTwo` , and thats why `text_data_delimiter: '<br>'` does not work for you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `text_data_delimiter: '<br>'` just make sure you got no white spaces in yout `<td>` cell, [see live sample here](https://jsbin.com/luqicumode/1/edit?html,js,output)

Code snippets:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  oTable = $('#example').dataTable().yadcf([
    {
      column_number : 0,
      text_data_delimiter: '<br>'
    }]);
});
```

HTML:

```
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Some Data</th>
        <th>More Data</th>
        <th>Yes / No</th>
        <th>Values</th>
        <th>Tags</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td>One<br>Two</td>
        <td>More Data 11</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>a_value,b_value</td>
        <td><span class="label lightblue">Tag1</span><span class="label lightblue">Tag2</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="even gradeC">
        <td>Three<br>Four</td>
        <td>More Data 22</td>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>b_value,c_value</td>
        <td><span class="label lightblue">Tag1</span><span class="label lightblue">Tag3</span></td>
      </tr>      
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Hi I can't get this to work. Am I missing something in my configuration?`{
 column_number: 3,
 data: uniqueListNames,
 select_type: "Select",
 text_data_delimiter: "<br>",
 filter_default_label: "Filter By List",
 filter_reset_button_text: false
}`

This is the contents of my <td> 

`<td>List1,List2</td>`

Comment: 1) [data](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L48) is mostly usefull for case in which you want to populate your filter with predifined set of values (unless you use the [append_data_to_table_data](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L63) ) , as to the delimiter, it seems that you are using the `,` between your values of the `td` , without a link to a working sample I wont be able to help you.

Comment: I'm using underscore.js uniq to create an array of unique 'list names' and passing that to the data element:

`uniqueListNames = _.uniq(fullNamesList);`

` yadcf.init(cTbl, [
 {
  column_number: 3,
  text_data_delimiter: "<br>",
  data: uniqueListNames,
  select_type: "Select",
  filter_default_label: "Filter By List",
  filter_reset_button_text: false
 }`
text_data_delimiter doesn't work for any characters.

Comment: By using the `data` you are telling yadcf not to populate the filter from the table column but rather from the `data` array on which the `text_data_delimiter` has no effect, see jsbin for example: http://jsbin.com/joceyesibu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: OK got it. So, I have repeating data in my rows, but want the Select to display only the unique values. Is there a way to achieve this within yadcf itself (i.e. so I can split the values in the TD)?

Comment: Yes, see sample and notice the values, http://jsbin.com/wacarizoyo/edit?html,js,output but you must verify that you got no redundant white spaces in your `td`, in the jsbin sample I posted I dont have extra white spaces and so should you for the `text_data_delimiter` to work properly

Answer (score 0):

I came back to this today and solved it in datatables, specifically in the 'render' option.

If there was more than one country name in the data row, I parsed the array and added a BR. This makes the country names display on separate lines in the TD.

```
'render': function (data, string, row) {

    var countryNames = "";

    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        countryNames += item + "<br />";
    })

    return countyNames;
}
```