# Tag selection in table (rendered_html with filter_match_mode=exact)

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I'm using DataTables with yadcf. I'd like to implement tag selection. I found the example here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35254351/2604492

But it uses `filter_match_mode=contains` (the default), which means that if there are e.g. two tags, `php` and `not-php`, choosing `php` will match `not-php` too as the former is contained in the latter.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/o7hv6qpy/

With `filter_match_mode=exact` it just stops working.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve it is to use the `custom_func` like shown below.

You can put your `exact` logic into the `custom_func` implementation

```
yadcf.init(table, [
    {
    column_number : 1,
    column_data_type: "rendered_html",
    html_data_type: "text",
    filter_default_label: "Select tag",
    text_data_delimiter: ',',
    filter_type: 'custom_func',
    custom_func: myCustomFilterFunction
  }
]);

function myCustomFilterFunction(filterVal, columnVal) {
    const items = columnVal.split(',');
    return items.some(function(arrVal) {
        return filterVal === arrVal;
    });
}
```